# How to fix Rails Active Storage blobs sharing the same ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

I'm coming across an issue where when creating or editing my Pet model instances, there's a chance that the active storage blob id shares the same value as another existing Pet's blob id causing images to not be uniquely related to one pet instance. ie. Different unique pets sharing the same active storage blob id

I tried looking for any answers and understanding what's happening, but can't seem to figure out why the blobs are being shared.

The Pet controller used to create and update pets.

```rb
class Api::V1::PetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_pet, only: [:update, :show, :destroy]

  def index
    @pets = Pet.all
    render json: @pets
  end

  def show
    render json: @pet
  end

  def create
    @pet = Pet.create(pet_params)
    @pet.image.attach(io: image_io, filename: image_name)
    render json: @pet, status: :created
  end

  def update
    @pet.update(pet_params)
    if params[:image]
      @pet.image.attach(io: image_io, filename: image_name)
    end
    render json: @pet, status: :OK
  end

  def destroy
    @pet.destroy
    render json: @pet, status: :deleted
  end

  private

  def find_pet
    @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def pet_params
    params.permit(:name, :birthdate, :breed, :missing, :user_id, :instagram, :posters_id)
  end

  def image_io
    decoded_image = Base64.decode64(params[:image])
    StringIO.new(decoded_image)
  end

  def image_name
    params[:file_name]
  end

end
```

Expected every created or edited pet to have their own unique blob.

The current database has 4 pet instances sharing the same blob ID thus making them share the same image.